# Javascript plugin: scrolling based animations

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

I worked in a [Javascript plugin](https://github.com/IanCaio/ScrollingAnimation) the last couple of days, to implement scrolling based animations in websites. It's functional at the moment (here is the [project page](https://iancaio.github.io/ScrollingAnimation/) with a small demo). The code is a bit large for the standards here I guess (304 lines, counting the comments), but I'll also let you guys know specific stuff about the code I'd like some feedback on, if you don't feel like reading the whole thing!.

I also wrote an [article](https://iancaio.github.io/blog/front-end/2018/03/04/a-guide-to-scrolling-animation.html) in my blog explaining the scripts functionality that can be used as a reference to the code structure if something looks confusing. But I guess the project page and the code itself shouldn't be too tricky to understand!

```
var ScrollingAnimation = function (ControlledObjects, AnimationBeginningState, AnimationEndingState,
                BeginningTriggeringPoint, EndingTriggeringPoint, Configuration) {
    // Get the controlled objects, which will converted to an array with all the IDs if necessary:
    this.CO = ControlledObjects instanceof Array ? ControlledObjects.slice() : [ControlledObjects];
    // Convert the string IDs to DOM elements (requires Polyfill for Browsers < IE9)
    this.CO = this.CO.map(function(element){
        return document.getElementById(element);
    });

    // Get the animation beginning and ending states
    this.ABS = Object.assign({}, AnimationBeginningState);
    this.AES = Object.assign({}, AnimationEndingState);
    if (this.validateAnimStates(this.ABS, this.AES) === false) {
        console.error("[ScrollingAnimation] Error: The animation state objects have unmatched keys!");
        return null;
    }

    // Get the beginning and ending triggers
    this.BTP = Object.assign({id: null, posY: 0}, BeginningTriggeringPoint);
    this.ETP = Object.assign({id: null, posY: 0}, EndingTriggeringPoint);

    // Initial state and ratio
    this.state = 0;
    this.ratio = 0; // The ratio of the current position in relation to BTP and ETP

    // Those store the values of the state and ratio in the last iteration and are used to check if either the state
    // or the ratio has changed. We only call the updateStyle method if one of them has changed.
    // They start as -1 to force the first loop to recognize a change in the state/ratio and call updateStyle.
    this.oldState = -1;
    this.oldRatio = -1;

    // Set the configurations or use the defaults if none is given
    // killOnEnd: When it's true, the animation will stop once it reaches the "Done" state. The default is false.
    // callback: Specifies a function to be called on state/ratio changes. The default is null (no function).
    var defaultConfig = { killOnEnd: false, callback: null };
    this.config = (typeof Configuration === 'undefined') ? defaultConfig : Object.assign(defaultConfig, Configuration);

    //Bind methods
    this.update = this.update.bind(this);

    //Later change for animation frames
    this.intervalID = setInterval(this.update, 16);
}

// General update function
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.update = function(){
    this.checkState();
    this.checkRatio();
    // Did we have a change in the state or ratio?
    if (this.state !== this.oldState || this.ratio !== this.oldRatio) {
        this.oldState = this.state;
        this.oldRatio = this.ratio;

        // If we set a callback function, call it with the state and ratio as arguments
        if (this.config.callback) {
            this.config.callback(this.state, this.ratio);
        }

        this.updateStyle();
    }
}

// Returns a rgba(r,g,b,a) string from an object with red, green, blue and alpha fields
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.colorFromObj = function (obj) {
    return "rgba(" + parseInt(obj.red) + "," + parseInt(obj.green) + "," + parseInt(obj.blue) + "," + obj.alpha + ")";
}

// Checks if two objects are equivalent
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.areEquivalent = function (obj1, obj2) {
    var props1 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1);
    var props2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2);

    if (props1.length !== props2.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < props1.length; i++){
        var prop = props1[i];

        if (obj1[prop] !== obj2[prop]){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// Updates the style for each Controlled Object
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.updateStyle = function(){
    if (this.state === 0){
        // Style matches the ABS
        this.CO.forEach(function(element, index){
            var currentProp;

            for (prop in this.ABS){
                currentProp = this.ABS[prop];

                // Some properties need to be assigned in a special way, since they are not
                // represented only by a number (ie: backgroundColor and color, since they are
                // represented with an object having "red", "green", "blue" and "alpha" keys. Or
                // position properties that need "px" appended).
                switch (prop) {
                    case "backgroundColor":
                    case "color":
                        element.style[prop] = this.colorFromObj(currentProp);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                    case "right":
                    case "top":
                    case "bottom":
                        // If we don't explicitly choose an unit, either here or on AES, default is pixels
                        if(!this.extractUnit(currentProp)){
                            currentProp = currentProp + (this.extractUnit(this.AES[prop]) || "px");
                        }
                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                        break;
                    default:
                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                }
            }
        }, this);
    } else if (this.state === 2){
        // Style matches the AES
        this.CO.forEach(function(element, index){
            var currentProp;

            for (prop in this.AES){
                currentProp = this.AES[prop];

                // Some properties need to be assigned in a special way, since they are not
                // represented only by a number (ie: backgroundColor and color, since they are
                // represented with an object having "red", "green", "blue" and "alpha" keys. Or
                // position properties that need "px" appended).
                switch (prop) {
                    case "backgroundColor":
                    case "color":
                        element.style[prop] = this.colorFromObj(currentProp);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                    case "right":
                    case "top":
                    case "bottom":
                        // If we don't explicitly choose an unit, either here or on ABS, default is pixels
                        if(!this.extractUnit(currentProp)){
                            currentProp = currentProp + (this.extractUnit(this.ABS[prop]) || "px");
                        }
                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                        break;
                    default:
                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                }
            }
        }, this);
    } else {
        // Style is between ABS and AES
        this.CO.forEach(function(element, index){
            var currentProp;

            for (prop in this.AES){
                // Some properties need to be treated specially when assigning their value according to the ratio,
                // since they are not represented only by a number (ie: backgroundColor and color are represented
                // by an object with fields for red, green, blue and alpha values. Those values need to be updated
                // individually and then assigned to a new object which will represent the new backgroundColor/color
                // value).
                switch (prop) {
                    case "backgroundColor":
                    case "color":
                        var newRed = this.ABS[prop].red + (this.ratio * (this.AES[prop].red - this.ABS[prop].red));
                        var newGreen = this.ABS[prop].green + (this.ratio * (this.AES[prop].green - this.ABS[prop].green));
                        var newBlue = this.ABS[prop].blue + (this.ratio * (this.AES[prop].blue - this.ABS[prop].blue));
                        var newAlpha = this.ABS[prop].alpha + (this.ratio * (this.AES[prop].alpha - this.ABS[prop].alpha));

                        currentProp = { red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: newAlpha };

                        element.style[prop] = this.colorFromObj(currentProp);
                        break;
                    case "left":
                    case "right":
                    case "top":
                    case "bottom":
                        // Get the real values of the property in the ABS and AES (i.e.: "10px" -> 10)
                        var ABSVal = parseFloat(this.ABS[prop]);
                        var AESVal = parseFloat(this.AES[prop]);

                        // Calculate the current value of the property according to the ratio
                        currentProp = (ABSVal + (this.ratio * (AESVal - ABSVal)));

                        // Get the unit from either the ABS or AES property
                        var unit = (this.extractUnit(this.ABS[prop]) || this.extractUnit(this.AES[prop]));
                        // If we still don't have a unit, default is pixels
                        currentProp = currentProp + (unit || "px");

                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                        break;
                    default:
                        currentProp = this.ABS[prop] + (this.ratio * (this.AES[prop] - this.ABS[prop]));

                        element.style[prop] = currentProp;
                }
            }
        }, this);
    }
}

// Extracts unit from a string representing a value (i.e.: "10px" -> "px");
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.extractUnit = function (str) {
    // Is the value a string? (user can write unitless non-string 0, which is a valid position value in CSS
    //  or even write a unitless non-string number expecting the default unit "px" to be applied)
    if (typeof str.substr !== 'undefined') {
        // What is the length of the part of the string that represent the value?
        var numberLength = parseFloat(str).toString().length;

        // Extract the unit part of the string
        return str.substr(numberLength);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

// Checks if the ABP and AES objects have the same keys (and nothing else)
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.validateAnimStates = function (obj1, obj2) {
    var keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
    var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);

    if (keys1.length === keys2.length) {
        return keys1.every( function (key) {
            if (keys2.indexOf(key) >= 0){
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}

// Checks the current animation ratio
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.checkRatio = function () {
    if (this.state === 0) {
        this.ratio = 0;
    } else if (this.state === 2){
        this.ratio = 1;
    } else {
        // Absolute positions of the BTP and ETP, and total distance between them
        var BTPPos;
        var ETPPos;
        var total;

        if (this.BTP.id) {
            // Accounts for the offset too, if there is one
            BTPPos = document.getElementById(this.BTP.id).getBoundingClientRect().top + this.BTP.posY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else {
            BTPPos = this.BTP.posY;
        }
        if (this.ETP.id) {
            // Accounts for the offset too, if there is one
            ETPPos = document.getElementById(this.ETP.id).getBoundingClientRect().top + this.ETP.posY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else {
            ETPPos = this.ETP.posY;
        }
        total = ETPPos - BTPPos;

        this.ratio = parseFloat(window.pageYOffset - BTPPos)/total;
    }
}

// Checks the current animation state
ScrollingAnimation.prototype.checkState = function () {
    // Check if we crossed the BTP
    // Are we using a DOM element or absolute position?
    if (this.BTP.id) {
        var BTPTop = document.getElementById(this.BTP.id).getBoundingClientRect().top;
        //Did we cross the BTP? (if we have posY, it's used as an offset)
        if (BTPTop <= (-this.BTP.posY)) {
            this.state = 1; //We will check later if we are actually in the state 2
        } else {
            this.state = 0;
        }
    } else {
        //Did we cross the BTP?
        if (window.pageYOffset >= this.BTP.posY) {
            this.state = 1; //We will check later if we are actually in the state 2
        } else {
            this.state = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if we crossed the ETP
    // Are we using a DOM element or absolute position?
    if (this.ETP.id) {
        var ETPTop = document.getElementById(this.ETP.id).getBoundingClientRect().top;
        //Did we cross the ETP? (if we have posY, it's used as an offset)
        if (ETPTop <= (-this.ETP.posY)) {
            this.state = 2;
        }
    } else {
        //Did we cross the ETP?
        if (window.pageYOffset >= this.ETP.posY) {
            this.state = 2;
        }
    }

    if (this.config.killOnEnd && this.state === 2) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
    }
}
```

---

I still need to change the update callback to either use requested animation frames instead of intervals (adding the proper polyfill to support IE9) or be called by the `onscroll` event (which sounds like the best option in terms of performance). That's something kind of easy to change, but so far I was working on other features and the documentation, so I didn't do it yet.

### Specific feedback

Here is some stuff I'm interested in regarding the code, if you don't feel like reading it all!

- I don't currently follow any JS style guidelines (to be honest, the last one I saw advised semicolons not to be used unless strictly necessary, and this just sounds very bad to me), but I tried to follow a couple of rules, like camelCase naming, keeping the spacing and indentation consistent. I was just wondering about the overall look of the code, is it easy on the eyes or would any collaborator hate me when working on my code?
- Is the code self explanatory? Can people understanding what I'm doing on at least most of the code when reading it? Did I extract enough functions from it, or do I still have too many sections of the code that require extraction?
- In terms of performance, is the code efficient? I know I'm still using 16ms timeouts, but consider for this that this will be soon be changed to either a `onscroll` event callback or a `requestedAnimationFrame`. Opinions on which one is a better option are also welcome! `onscroll` sounds like the solution, but I was wondering about the reliability of the event (maybe it has some bugs on some browsers that would not fire the callback in some situations?).
- And of course, any feedback on the project and its functionality itself would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1. consider using JSDoc to add comments above your functions.
2. Your comments sometimes start with a space, e.g. `// Here` and sometime dont `//Here` be consistent.
3. With `this.validateAnimStates(this.ABS, this.AES) === false` you can use `!this.validateAnimStates(this.ABS, this.AES)`

Comment: Thanks! I'll check JSDocs, but I quickly read their website and it looks good! I changed the comments and the validation code as suggested (just need to push the changes to the repo).